# How to get the path to the temp folder

Tags: best-practices

I need to create a temporary file. I'd like to save it in the temp folder, but I'm not sure what's the best way of getting the full path of this folder.
If I use `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.TempFolderPath` it only gives me the folder name, not the full path.
Is there any helper or similar that gives me this information?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for MapPath (combined with TempFolderPath)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### For a temporary file

Actually, Sitecore itself doesn't use TempFolderPath when it needs to create a temporary file.

Looking inside the Sitecore PackageManager classes, Sitecore does this when it needs a temporary file.

```
string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
```

#### Using TempFolderPath

The thing about this setting is; it *can* be relative to the current web root folder, but it could also be defined as an *absolute path* (outside your webroot) in which case a MapPath call could fail.

Sitecore has a utility class that deals with this. You can find it in FileUtil, so your code would look like this:

```
string tempFolder = Sitecore.IO.FileUtil.MapPath(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.TempFolderPath);
```

This snippet would work, with both relative and absolute path definitions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
string tempFullPath = Sitecore.MainUtil.MapPath(Settings.TempFolderPath);
```

or

```
string tempFullPath = Sitecore.IO.FileUtil.MapPath(Settings.TempFolderPath);
```